# Converting a text into a transposed dataframe whilst retaining filename (pandas in python)

Tags: python, pandas

**The Problem**

I have multiple result files which I would like to transpose and append to a csv file but also take the input filename as a cell in the csv. However, the results files have a few lines at the beginning which I am not interested in.

**Input data**

Here is an example of the input data, I only want the 'Codon' column and the 'Fraction' column in my output:

```
#CdsCount: 1727

#Coding GC 31.31%
#1st letter GC 40.68%
#2nd letter GC 30.71%
#3rd letter GC 22.53%

#Codon AA Fraction Frequency Number
GCA    A     0.491    26.008  13458
GCC    A     0.074     3.946   2042
GCG    A     0.073     3.855   1995
GCT    A     0.362    19.202   9936
TGC    C     0.269     3.596   1861
TGT    C     0.731     9.773   5057
GAC    D     0.282    16.152   8358
GAT    D     0.718    41.196  21317
GAA    E     0.878    67.661  35011
GAG    E     0.122     9.388   4858
TTC    F     0.242     8.942   4627
TTT    F     0.758    28.028  14503
GGA    G     0.317    19.627  10156
GGC    G     0.133     8.229   4258
GGG    G     0.097     6.020   3115
GGT    G     0.453    28.034  14506
CAC    H     0.487     7.019   3632
CAT    H     0.513     7.384   3821
ATA    I     0.418    39.884  20638
ATC    I     0.133    12.649   6545
ATT    I     0.449    42.795  22144
AAA    K     0.869    80.385  41595
AAG    K     0.131    12.113   6268
CTA    L     0.049     4.383   2268
CTC    L     0.035     3.200   1656
CTG    L     0.012     1.046    541
CTT    L     0.144    13.022   6738
TTA    L     0.601    54.222  28057
TTG    L     0.159    14.336   7418
ATG    M     1.000    25.150  13014
AAC    N     0.252    18.616   9633
AAT    N     0.748    55.285  28607
CCA    P     0.388    12.142   6283
CCC    P     0.095     2.968   1536
CCG    P     0.089     2.800   1449
CCT    P     0.428    13.398   6933
CAA    Q     0.796    16.404   8488
CAG    Q     0.204     4.207   2177
AGA    R     0.595    17.335   8970
AGG    R     0.186     5.425   2807
CGA    R     0.089     2.582   1336
CGC    R     0.008     0.244    126
CGG    R     0.022     0.638    330
CGT    R     0.100     2.916   1509
AGC    S     0.087     5.336   2761
AGT    S     0.226    13.818   7150
TCA    S     0.325    19.863  10278
TCC    S     0.081     4.957   2565
TCG    S     0.054     3.287   1701
TCT    S     0.226    13.808   7145
ACA    T     0.401    20.599  10659
ACC    T     0.141     7.236   3744
ACG    T     0.108     5.570   2882
ACT    T     0.349    17.932   9279
GTA    V     0.422    26.656  13793
GTC    V     0.050     3.160   1635
GTG    V     0.092     5.834   3019
GTT    V     0.435    27.444  14201
TGG    W     1.000     5.858   3031
TAC    Y     0.310    13.369   6918
TAT    Y     0.690    29.729  15383
TAA    *     0.908     3.030   1568
TAG    *     0.052     0.172     89
TGA    *     0.041     0.135     70
```

**Desired output**

Here is an example of the output I would like, with the filename of the input file as another column, as I'm going to be running this thousands of times the code should be as efficient as possible and append to a single results file:

```
+----------------------------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+-----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|                                        |  GCA  |  GCC  |  GCG  |  GCT  |  TGC  |  TGT  |  GAC  |  GAT  |  GAA  |  GAG  |  TTC  |  TTT  |  GGA  |  GGC  |  GGG  |  GGT  |  CAC  |  CAT  |  ATA  |  ATC  |  ATT  |  AAA  |  AAG  |  CTA  |  CTC  |  CTG  |  CTT  |  TTA  |  TTG  | ATG |  AAC  |  AAT  |  CCA  |  CCC  |  CCG  |  CCT  |  CAA  |  CAG  |  AGA  |  AGG  |  CGA  |  CGC  |  CGG  | CGT |  AGC  |  AGT  |  TCA  |  TCC  |  TCG  |  TCT  |  ACA  |  ACC  |  ACG  |  ACT  |  GTA  | GTC  |  GTG  |  GTT  | TGG | TAC  | TAT  |  TAA  |  TAG  |  TGA  |
+----------------------------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+-----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| GCF_000006175.1_ASM617v2_genomic.codon | 0.491 | 0.074 | 0.073 | 0.362 | 0.269 | 0.731 | 0.282 | 0.718 | 0.878 | 0.122 | 0.242 | 0.758 | 0.317 | 0.133 | 0.097 | 0.453 | 0.487 | 0.513 | 0.418 | 0.133 | 0.449 | 0.869 | 0.131 | 0.049 | 0.035 | 0.012 | 0.144 | 0.601 | 0.159 |   1 | 0.252 | 0.748 | 0.388 | 0.095 | 0.089 | 0.428 | 0.796 | 0.204 | 0.595 | 0.186 | 0.089 | 0.008 | 0.022 | 0.1 | 0.087 | 0.226 | 0.325 | 0.081 | 0.054 | 0.226 | 0.401 | 0.141 | 0.108 | 0.349 | 0.422 | 0.05 | 0.092 | 0.435 |   1 | 0.31 | 0.69 | 0.908 | 0.052 | 0.041 |
+----------------------------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+-----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**My code so far:**

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

outfile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
list = []
for line in outfile:
    if "codon" in line.lower():
        list.append(line)
        for line in outfile:
            list.append(line)

df = pd.DataFrame({str(outfile):list})
df.to_csv('testresults.csv')
```

This gets the appropriate lines from the results file and converts the results to a csv with the file name as the column, although it doesn't transpose the results and the format of the csv is incorrect.

Comment: `df.pivot(index='file_name', columns='Codon', values='Fraction')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read each file into a separate dataframe and add a column with the filename you can concatenate them together and use DataFrame.pivot.

```
# list of all your files:
files = ['codons1.txt','codons2.txt']

col_names =['codon','aa','fraction','frequency','number']

dfs = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file,sep='\s+',comment='#',names=col_names)
    df['filename'] = file
    dfs.append(df)

# Concatenate all the dataframes together:
all_data = pd.concat(dfs)

# And pivot into the desired format:
output = all_data.pivot(index='filename',columns='codon',values='fraction')

# And write to file:
output.to_csv('testresults.csv')
```